# Get the type of a List

Tags: vb.net, list, serialization, types

I am using Visual Basic.net 2012.

How can I get the type of a List that I have loaded from serialization?

I can get the type of a single object as follows:

`ObjectFromFile.GetType.Name`

I have tried the following, with no result:

```
dim t as Type = (ObjectFromFile.GetGenericArguments())(0)
```

How can I find the type of a list?

Comment: Can you put the declaration/instantiation code of the list. Many times, calling  t.ToString() returns the type as string;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. This:

```
Dim tt As Type = ObjectFromFile.GetType.GetGenericArguments()(0)
```

should give you the type of list's items.